# Can't solve this little bug. The code is below. Karen is not responding to input

Tags: python

Karen is not responding to user input. What did i do wrong?

```
def menu1():
    main = 'True'
    hello = 'Hi!'
    status = 'How are you?'
    print ('>> Hello! My name is Karen, you can ask me anything you want!')
    while main == 'True':
        karen = input(">> Talk to Karen: ")
    if karen == hello:
        print (">> Hi there!")
    elif karen == status:
        print (">> I'm fine, what about you?")
    else:
        print (">> I don't think I understand.")

def menu2():
    print ('>> menu2')

def menu3():
    print ('>> menu3')

def menu4():
    print ('>> Goodbye!')
    sys.exit

ans = True
while ans:
    print ('\n>> --- MENU --- <<')
    print("""
    >> 1. AI Karen - Beta
    >> 2. Menu 2 - Soon
    >> 3. Menu 3 - Soon
    >> 4. Exit
    """)
    ans=input(">> Select an option: ")
    if ans=="1":
        menu1()
    elif ans=="2":
        menu2()
    elif ans=="3":
        menu3()
    elif ans=="4":
        menu4()
        ans = None
    else:
        print(">> That is not an option!")
```

Anticipated thanks!

Comment: My guess: ``if karen == hello:`` and the following lines need to be indented to be part of the ``while`` loop. Currently you have an endless loop that only asks for new input from the user and does nothing else.

Comment: Please add what you're Trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition of the while loop is always true so it loops indefinitely on the input, after the input set main to false like this and it will work

```
while main == 'True':
    karen = input(">> Talk to Karen: ")
    main = False
```

Comment: If this solved you question, please select this as the correct answer. Thank you